# Angular6 - FormControlName - TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have loginForm in my project [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rhrd4?embed=1&file=src/app/login/login.component.html)

But I get an error at 'formControlName':

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at
>   Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (LoginComponent.html:7) at
>   Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23910) at
>   checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23306) at callViewAction (core.js:23547)
>   at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23489) at checkAndUpdateView
>   (core.js:23312) at callViewAction (core.js:23547) at
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23510) at checkAndUpdateView
>   (core.js:23307) at callViewAction (core.js:23547)

My login component:

```
  initForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required ],
    password: ['', Validators.required]     
   });
    }
```

I don't understand where the error appears.

my input-field component [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rhrd4?embed=1&file=src/app/ui/input-field/input-field.component.ts)

```
 value:string;
 onChange: ()=> void;
 onTouched: ()=> void;
 disabled:boolean;
  ngOnInit() {
   }
  writeValue(value: string): void {
  this.value = value ? value: '';  
   }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
   this.onChange =fn;
   }
   registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
   this.onTouched=fn;
   }
   setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
   this.disabled = isDisabled;
   }
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a small function to return controls in a cleaner way so in you html you could have the example given below. The error is related to how you are trying to access your controls.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="email.dirty">
```

And then return the control so you have proper get access. Looking like so.

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms'; //correct type to return.


public get email(): AbstractControl
{
    return this.loginForm.controls.email
}
```

This will then allow you to access you controls for the respective form group. You could write one for each control you would like to access.You could also return the form and then just access the control you would like. This above stops the errors in you stackblitz and shows the result in the `JSON` on screen. Comment if you have any trouble.

A nice benefit of this is that in your controller as well as template you can use it to perform quick checks.

```
if (this.email.valid)
{
    // any logic where you require a specific form control to be valid.
}
```

[Documentation for Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Answer (score 3):

referring to your code at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rhrd4?embed=1&file=src/app/ui/input-field/input-field.component.ts)

This is your form

```
this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required ],
      password: ['', Validators.required]     
    });
```

and in HTML
you have missed the form name

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <app-input-field formControlName="email"></app-input-field>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').dirty && personalProfileForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
          email Required
        </div>
        <app-input-field formControlName="password"></app-input-field>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').dirty && personalProfileForm.get('password').hasError('required')">
          password Required
        </div>
      </div>
```

Just replace `personalProfileForm` with `loginForm` in your html

Additionally, advice by @dince12 is perfect in order to make your html code looks more easy to read, cheers!

If you want more details on that example, you can refer below article :
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example 
and below is an small example:

> create public property like this

```
public get myform() { return this.myform.controls; }
```

> and use it like this

```
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && myform.firstName.errors }" />
                            <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                                <div *ngIf="myform.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I glanced straight over the control name being wrong haha :-) good eye.

Comment: yeah, because I became curious to see the error reported when code was looking fine, also, your recommended property will always make sure that this issue never happens again